# REST : different representations of the same data

Tags: json, rest

How to structure an API where the same data may request in different format, in a RESTful format. For example.

```
GET /person/<id>  //get the details of resource <id>
```

Now depending on the client (browser) requirement, the data may send as html (say normal rendering) or Json (say ajax call). So my doubts are

1. Can I keep the same url for both requests, or should keep them seperate?
2. How to detect whether the request is for html/Json at the server. The request type is same (GET). So which parameter should I consider.
3. How to detect the difference in data type at client (html/Json)\

thanks,

bsr.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Similar question: [REST Content-Type: Should it be based on extension or Accept header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/381568/rest-content-type-should-it-be-based-on-extension-or-accept-header)

The accepted answers has great points.

> Can I keep the same url for both requests, or should keep them seperate?

Yes, keep them the same. Its the same resource, you're just asking for different representations of it.

> How to detect whether the request is for html/Json at the server. The request type is same (GET). So which parameter should I consider.

You can use the Accept header to specify the return content-type.

> How to detect the difference in data type at client (html/Json)\

You would look at the "Content-Type" header.

Comment: For your own sanity during development it may be useful to add a URL parameter or another distinct URL (/person/<id>.json) in order to allow you to override the Accept header for testing purposes. It's kind of a pain to have to use cURL or other means to check the results of your service in another representation. Otherwise I'm 100% in agreement with Mr-sk.

Comment: for more info, see sec. 12 of HTTP spec (http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec12.html#sec12)

Answer (score 0):

What about adding a variable for output type?

Comment: That would not be RESTful. URLs, including URL parameters, are for specifying resources, not their representation. The accepted way to specify output type is the `Accept` header.