# RESTful endpoint returning multiple different structures?

Tags: http, rest, endpoints

Looking at a third party API (HTTP) and it can return data (XML) in different structures (NOT different types - JSON, XML) depending on parameters supplied in the query string to an endpoint.

Is this a good idea for a RESTful service endpoint?

Answer (score 1):

It is also recommended to use the `HTTP Accept Header` to specify which representation is requested. Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/381568/367285) discussion.

Comment: not talking about different representations of the same data, talking about different data