# Is that possible that the web-page can be restricted from mobile access? Gives 404 erro

Tags: iphone, xml, extjs, sencha-touch, http-status-code-404

Have an issue with the following url:
http://www.mix1011.com.au/m_app/entertainment/zooey-deschanel-no-bangs

I can acces the url from my laptop, however when I'm testing my mobile app, it gives me 404 error... Well, my understanding would be that the web-site restricts access from mobile devices.

Could you explain how to troubleshoot this issue?

Comment: Look at this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8878291/why-does-my-web-service-produce-an-xml-result-for-most-mobile-browsers-instead-o

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not that the access is restricted. What is happening is that it's redirecting to a mobile site which doesn't have the page that you're looking for. When you try to access your URL from a mobile browser, a 302 redirect is sent with this data:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Connection: close
Date: Sat, 11 May 2013 20:45:46 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Server: Live6
X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727
Location: http://m.mix1011.com.au/m/m_app/entertainment/zooey-deschanel-no-bangs
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 187

<html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body>
<h2>Object moved to <a href="http://m.mix1011.com.au/m/m_app/entertainment/zooey-deschanel-no-bangs">here</a>.</h2>
</body></html>
```

That webpage, however, does not exist on m.mix1011.com.au so a 404 is returned on that domain:

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Connection  close
Date    Sat, 11 May 2013 20:45:46 GMT
Server  Microsoft-IIS/6.0
X-Powered-By    ASP.NET
Server  Live7
X-AspNet-Version    2.0.50727
Cache-Control   private
Content-Length  0
```

Most HTTP proxies will allow you to monitor this happening - I used [Charles Proxy](http://www.charlesproxy.com). Just leave it running while accessing the webpage in the iPhone simulator. You can also use Firefox and change the browser's User Agent to Mobile Safari.

You can get around this issue by changing the user agent (assuming you're using a UIWebView):

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Your user agent", @"UserAgent", nil];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:dictionary];
```

Comment: Sorry how did you get this, as when I try to resive an `failure response` I recieve: the url: `http://www.mix1011.com.au/m_app/entertainment/zooey-deschanel-no-bangs`

What did you use?

Comment: Definitely looks like a great answer

Comment: Actually to be clear, I used Safari in the iPhone Simulator to access the webpage while leaving Charles running to monitor the connection - you'll see the redirect happening.

Comment: I added a workaround for you in the answer too in the latest edit, just FYI in case you missed it. Cheers!