# How to specify mime-type in URL to specify JSON from RESTful web service

Tags: json, rest, url, mime-types

Can anyone tell me if it is possible to specify mime-type returned from a RESTful web service through the URL?  I am trying to demo a simple service that I created to someone and I am just using a web browser (Chrome) to invoke the service.  I am trying things like this:

`http://localhost:8088/providers?mimeType={application/json}`
`http://localhost:8088/providers?mimeType=application/json`
`http://localhost:8088/providers?mimeType=json`

None of these work for me - I just keep getting XML returned no matter what I select.

I found several posts related to this subject, but nothing with an answer about how to do this through a URL (I found some which talked about setting headers, but I am using a browser and don't have the ability to specify headers).  I found this post:

[REST Content-Type: Should it be based on extension or Accept header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/381568/rest-content-type-should-it-be-based-on-extension-or-accept-header)

And that post linked to this:  http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2004/08/11/rest.html

On the xml.com site, I found this text:

> > URI-Specified Representation [PS, AR]
> >     A client can specify the representation using the following query string:
> >
> > mimeType={mime-type}
> >     A REST server should support this query.

So it seems that what I am trying to do should be possible, but I can't figure out how to make it work.  Can anyone help?

Thanks.

Comment: It really depends o the API you are using. What is this API ? What says its doc about returning JSON ?

Comment: Pascal,  I am using Talend for ESB which is creating Java code based on a GUI-style IDE.  I can't find much info from Talend on this; however, the code is in Java so maybe you can tell me what to look for with the Java code.  Then maybe I can answer your question.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To define the headers added to your request, you can use a Chrome extension like [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm).

Then you will be able to [specify an Accept header to tell Talend to return json](http://www.talendforge.org/forum/viewtopic.php?id=23968):

```
Accept: Application/json
```

Comment: Thanks, Pascal - that worked.  Is there any way to do this purely through the URL?

Comment: As far as I know, it's not possible.