# Form Headers Prior to Postback

Tags: javascript, forms, post, submit

I have a submit input in a form with an onclick method. The onclick method correctly adjusts the action of the form and allows the form to submit (submission is handled naturally, not through a javascript submit). What I need to do is add a http request header (X-Requested-With = XMLHttpRequest to be exact). Is there a way to ensure the form post is sent with that header? The post cannot be submitted via javascript using the form.submit() method.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/374885/can-i-change-the-headers-of-the-http-request-send-by-the-browser) what you're asking for is impossible in its current form.  However you *could* modify where the form submits too.  For example POST to:

`www.mysite.com/XMLHttpRequest` or `www.mysite.com/NormalRequest`

so that the server understands the context of the request.

Comment: My issue is that I have a method that checks the http request header to see if it is an ajax call. Now, without realizing I would need it, I'm having to do a normal POST call. Without that added header as a check, the page will not load correctly. The AJAX javascript in the answer you posted is what I need, only I need it for form posts instead.

Comment: Can you not modify your method?

Comment: I could. I plan to use a hidden field check to determine whether the header should even be checked in the first place. I was just hoping to use the same bit across the board. Thanks!